# Minitube and smtube not able to connect to youtube, but youtube works fine in browser

Tags: 15.04, firefox, internet, youtube, minitube

I have a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Mate 15.04 and have noticed that Youtube runs pretty slowly on it. I decided to try installing Minitube, but it said that it couldn't download "gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/..." I tried to install smtube, but it simply said that it couldn't connect to Youtube. I thought this was pretty weird because I had Youtube open in Firefox directly in the background.
[image: smtube failure with youtube working in the background]

The contents of my hosts file follow:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   RaspberryPi

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Is there any reason for Firefox to work, but not smtube or minitube?

Comment: I remember YouTube saying that its API had been updated, meaning older clients, such as those on iOS 5, would no longer work. Is it possible that these clients haven't been updated?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Good point. Minitube is 0.3 versions behind in the packages repository and smtube is 2 versions behind. One version ago smtube was completely rewritten. I will see if it works using the current version.

Comment: @Zacharee1 The new versions are not built for my processor and have errors when building... :(

Comment: then I don't think you can use them :/

Comment: @Zacharee1 Then I won't! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, at least for me:
I only wanted *a* youtube client. `mps-youtube` works quite well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using the following commands:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
sudo apt-get install smtube smplayer
```

In `smtube`, select the the dl program.